# RSpec - inspected result must be ASCII only

Tags: ruby, rspec

In my RSpec tests I need to use snippets of text with national characters. I'm getting an error:  `inspected result must be ASCII only or use the default external encoding`.

I placed `# encoding: UTF-8` in my RSpec file, but it doesn't make any difference.
I use Atom and I have UTF-8 as selected encoding in settings.
In my tests I used UTF-16 to make it work:

```
let(:chapter) do
      Elem.new(title: "ROZDZIA\u0141)
end

let(:chapter_body) do
      <<EOS
  ROZDZIAŁ
  EOS
end
```

Tests pass. But now I wanted to print it:

```
it 'prints' do
  p parse(chapter)
end
```

And I get an error. I placed `# encoding: UTF-8` in the module in which I create all classes.

I'll be grateful for any hints.

Comment: Can you please post your spec and the method the test is for? What version of Ruby do you use? Do the other files include `# encoding: UTF-8` too?

Comment: What version of Ruby do you use?

Comment: the newest one :) I've just installed it on a new machine

Comment: What is returned by `Encoding.default_external`? Did you complie Ruby with readline support? What happens if you use `puts` instead of `p`? Btw. since Ruby 2.0 `UTF-8` is the default, there is no need to use the `# encoding: UTF-8` magic comments anymore.

Comment: Encoding.default_external returns CP852. puts makes it pass without an error, but it just shows name of class instance, without any details about an object, and using inspect on that returns the same mistake again

Comment: I see you marked is as duplicate, but the problem is I want text to show in proper way. When encoding result of inject method, I receive not readable text

Comment: You have two options: Force an encoding like described in the answer or set your `default_external` encoding to UTF8. But your current mix of encodings will not work.

Comment: I tried solution from an old answer - .encode(Encoding.default_external) - but it gives me many more mistakes, e.g. Invalid Byte Sequense Error on UTF-8. I thought default_external is now UTF-8 in newer Ruby versions?

Comment: No, `default_external` depends your environment outside of Ruby. It seems like your computer thinks it is a good idea to use `CP852`. What OS do you use? Did you try to use Ruby's `-E` option to force another encoding?